# Sharing Internet access - Linux / Windows configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a Linux device (a smart camera) connected to a Windows 10 PC by Ethernet. Fixed IP addresses are mandated.

The camera needs Internet access. The PC does link to Internet by Wifi and gets a DHCP address.

Despite numerous attempts with network adapter sharing or bridging, I can't find a correct way to enable this routing. Note that the Internet connection as well as Ethernet link coexist seamlessly.

Comment: Why don't you just plug the camera into the LAN using ab ethernet port on your router?

Comment: For now, because the router is in another room :-)

Comment: @davidgo: I tried this to no avail. The Linux system complains about Destination Host Unreachable when pinging an IP.

Comment: An unreachable ping can, but does not always mean devices can't communicate. Can you advise all IP addresses and netmasks  assigned on your camera and on interfaces on your lcomputer and router. Also, it may be worth life oking at the ARP table on the PC before and after ping.

Comment: @davidgo: mh, you are asking a lot, I don't have this info handy (on the Ethernet side, 192.168.3.15 and ...3.1, 255.255.255.0). Anyway, the camera and PC do ping each other successfully, both in a direct connection or through the router.